# Run command when ethernet is disconnected

Tags: networking, network-manager

Is there a way to execute a command in ubuntu when an ethernet cable is disconnected/connected? There's a notification when a cable is plugged in or removed, so I assume there is some way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is well described on the Ubuntu wiki: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/OnNetworkConnectionRunScript

Comment: Please don't post link only answers, links might change. At least include a summary.

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site just disappears... :-( Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! ;-) You can always leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your material...